# Static files in Nginx, Gunicorn in Django

Tags: django, nginx, gunicorn, django-staticfiles

i have try every configuration that i found and the static files don't get loaded, so i doesn't know what's wrong.   I create the app using Pycharm.

Can someone give me a hand to fix this?

Here are the configurations.

settings.py

```
MEDIA_ROOT = ''
MEDIA_URL = '/Users/gcarranza/PycharmProjects/clouddemyTest/'

STATIC_ROOT = ''
STATIC_URL = '/Users/gcarranza/PycharmProjects/clouddemyTest/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = (
'/Users/gcarranza/PycharmProjects/clouddemyTest/static',)
```

nginx conf:

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  localhost;

    location /static/ {
        autoindex on;
        alias   /Users/gcarranza/PycharmProjects/clouddemyTest/static/; 
    } 
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000;
    }
}
```

Gunicorn:

```
gunicorn_django -b localhost:8000
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You got the root and url backwards. Should be:

```
STATIC_ROOT = '/Users/gcarranza/PycharmProjects/clouddemyTest/static/'
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

And same for media